# CXF cannot set ExceptionHandler for DefaultConnectingIOReactor

Tags: java, spring, cxf

I use cxf with default clients for my async http requests. In some cases, connectingIOReactor gets some RuntimeException and breaks the reactor.

```
org.apache.http.nio.reactor.IOReactorException: I/O dispatch worker terminated abnormally
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:359)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:221)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: HostnameVerifier, socket reset for TTL
            2 lines skipped for [org.apache.cxf]
    at org.apache.http.nio.conn.ssl.SSLIOSessionStrategy$1.verify(SSLIOSessionStrategy.java:188)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:371)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:541)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:120)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)
    ... 1 more
```

Whenever IOReactor throws exception, I always get message `Request cannot be executed; I/O reactor status: STOPPED`. I cannot send requests again till application is restarted.

I solved my problem by copying AsyncHTTPConduitFactory and set exceptionHandler for ioreactor manuelly. However, I couldn't find any way to set this exception handler via properties or without copying.

Is there any way to set exceptionHandler parameterized way?